# Debian KVM network setup

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge, bonding, debian-jessie

I have a server with 4 ethernet ports. I want to use two ports for link aggregation to be used for KVM (virtual guests). How can I go about setting this up properly?

Create the link agg first then the bridge?

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 1):

yes this is the right way of doing it, don't forget to define which nics are slaves of the bond using bond-slaves option

as an example this is the configuration I use on a few kvm servers:

    `auto bond0
    iface bond0 inet manual
       bond-miimon 100
       bond-mode 802.3ad
       bond-lacp-rate 4
       bond-slaves eth0 eth2`

auto bond0.32
   iface bond0.32 inet manual
       vlan-raw-device bond0

auto vmbr32
   iface vmbr32 inet static
      bridge_ports bond0.32
      bridge_stp off
      bridge_fd 0
      bridge_maxwait 60
      bridge_waitport 30
      address configuration...

This is for a static ip configuration with vlan support but it's very close to what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

bond two NICs together, and build a bridge on top of the bond. Then connect your VMs to the bridge, simple enough.

NIC+NIC > BOND > BRIDGE <-- VM